# Can I change the icon of forums/discussion boards shown in search results?

Tags: search-results, file-icons

I am running an intranet site based on Sharepoint 2013 online. On the site I have a number of internal forums/discussion boards. On the parent site of the forums I have a Content Search Webpart with the following query:

path:"https://example.com/forums"  contentclass:STS_Web Title<>Forums

This shows me all available forums, however the icon in front of every forum is just a grey box with a question mark in it and the alt-text: "Sorry, we can't find an image for this item". Is there a way I can define an image for a forum that will show up here? That would make that page look a lot better.